# Question formatting like a table

Tags: alignment

I am preparing a document that has some questions with boxes for answering? It's should look like this: (red marks indicates indentation/alignment)

[image: ![enter image description here]

I have created this instead which needs improvement. I tried to use a table but tables have some left side indentation that is not desired. How can I do the exact figure with proper alignment?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent Here is the question: The question is long enough in 2/3 sentences with a stem. The stem describes a scenario. 

\noindent Here is the fill in the blank or box for answering. \hfill             Total \fbox{\phantom{text}} types

\noindent The option box or fill in the blank may contain multiple lines but it should be the same length as the previous one. No m-
atter how long the question, length must be the same.  \hfill Total \fbox{\phantom{text}} fruits

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a `[t]`op-aligned `\parbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent Here is the question: The question is long enough in 2/3 sentences with a stem. The stem 
  describes a scenario. 

\bigskip

\noindent \parbox[t]{.6667\linewidth}{\strut Here is the fill in the blank or box for answering.}
  \hfill
  Total \fbox{\phantom{text}} types

\medskip

\noindent \parbox[t]{.6667\linewidth}{\strut The option box or fill in the blank may contain multiple 
  lines but it should be the same length as the previous one. No matter how long the question, length 
  must be the same.}
  \hfill
  Total \fbox{\phantom{text}} fruits

\end{document}
```

If you consistently have no paragraph indentation, you might as well `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` and drop the use of `\noindent`.

You can achieve a similar result/output using `tabular` in this way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\noindent Here is the question: The question is long enough in 2/3 sentences with a stem. The stem 
  describes a scenario. 

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{.6667\linewidth} @{} >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash} p{.3333\linewidth} @{}}
  Here is the fill in the blank or box for answering. &
  Total \fbox{\phantom{text}} types
  \\[\medskipamount]
  The option box or fill in the blank may contain multiple 
  lines but it should be the same length as the previous one. 
  No matter how long the question, length must be the same. &
  Total \fbox{\phantom{text}} fruits
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's great! Thanks.